# Why is this Floating Action Button not stickied/anchored to the right as expected?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have a FAB that is stickied OK with regards to the bottom of the screen:

[image]

...but it absolutely refuses to sticky/'anchor' itself at the right edge of the table, where I'd like it to be:

[image]

Why?

- [StackBlitz example](https://angular-cqtbsz.stackblitz.io/classifieds)
- [StackBlitz example editor](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cqtbsz)

Answer (score 1):

I think, there are some parent problems with width; But you can try a quick fix, change

```
right: 40px;
```

to

```
left: 100%;
```

It worked for me.